# Created Static Block Successfully if i clicked the block it will redirect to Category Page

Tags: magento2, phtml, static-block

inside href what should I do?.`<a href=""><p><img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/xyz.jpg"}}"  alt="" /></p></a>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add in href

```
<a href="{{store url='xyz.html'}}"><p><img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/xyz.jpg"}}"  alt="" /></p></a>
```

If you want same page then add :

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)"><p><img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/xyz.jpg"}}"  alt="" /></p></a>
```

Comment: please vote so another person use the same